# Oracle Forms: Wrong number or types of arguments in call to '<'

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

How to solve the error, wrong number or types of arguments in call to '<', in the pl/sql code? This is my code:

```
DECLARE 
  A NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF :MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_YEAR < TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 365, 'YYYY'))
  THEN 
     A := SHOW_ALERT('ALERT_YEAR');
  END IF;
END;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the data type of `:MOTOR_PRODUCTS.MOTOR_YEAR`? You would get that error if, for example, the data type was `date` - you can't compare that to a number.

Comment: "SYSDATE - 365" smells like "last year". If that's so, what about leap years? That won't work correctly. Consider using `ADD_MONTHS` function instead, for example `extract(year from add_months(sysdate, -12))`

Comment: @Littlefoot - much simpler: `extract(year from sysdate) - 1`. But that will not answer the OP's question, which was about a "wrong data type" error.

Comment: @mathguy: certainly simpler (what was I thinking?!?). I know it won't fix a "wrong data type" issue, it was just a side remark while we're waiting for answer to your question.